# SSH RSA key with non-root user

Tags: ssh, user-accounts, rsa

I'm trying to secure my VPS (running Ubuntu 10.04) so I'm trying to use RSA authentication, obviously I don't want to be logging in as root, so I disabled `PermitRootLogin` but I also disabled `PasswordAuthentication`

My question is, how can I get my RSA key to authenticate with a regular user. Like I said, I got it to work with root while I had those settings enabled, but I have no idea how to make it work without them on, with a regular user.

Comment: Did you deactivate PasswordAuthentication _before_ you had a pubkey on the server?

Comment: No, I deactivated after I got the RSA key working with root, I thought it would just work with any other use too.

Comment: Well, you need a key in the authorized keys file for every user afaik. I think you have locked yourself from your server and need to contact support (although I might be wrong).

Comment: I'm not worried about locking myself out. How does the authorized_keys file determine which public key is for which user?

Comment: the user is determined by how you log in eg `ssh user@host`, the server then checks the users `.ssh` folder on the server for the authorized_keys file. I am guessing, but afterwards it maybe checks the `/etc/ssh/.ssh/authorized_keys file` (path might differ) for a fitting key. If you stored your root-pubkey in that file you should still be able to log in with another user, if you use the same private key.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put the public key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys or ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2 (mode 600) and have it work just like it does with the root account.

Execute these commands to correct permissions

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do a bit of set-up first on the server.

1. Generate your key (looks like you are good there)

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024 -C "Comment if you want it" -f id_arbitraty_name
   ```
2. Cat the Public (*.pub) key to the `authorized_keys` folder for the users you want to login as (As @John mentioned, 644 for these); the expansion will do it to both `authorized_keys` and `authorized_keys2`.

   ```
   cat id_arbitrary_name.pub >> /home/<username>/.ssh/authorized_keys{,2}
   ```
3. Download the private key

   ```
   scp user@server:/loc/on/server/id_arbitrary_name ~/.ssh/
   ```
4. Set safe permissions for the private key 600, since it's on your local machine

   ```
   chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_arbitrary_name
   ```

Optional:

5. If you want to save typing locally, set-up a local config file in ~/.ssh/

   ```
   vim ~/.ssh/config

   Host SomeIdentifyingName
       Hostname domain.com
       User username
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_arbitrary_name
   ```

That allows you to just type `ssh SomeIdentifyingName` (tab completion works on that!) and connect.

**Note**  Looks like you disabled root login, so this doesn't really apply to you. However, for future readers:

All the above being said, segregation of keys is suggested.  Otherwise, if I don't specify a username and the server prompts - root is an obvious one to try!

Comment: Might I suggest a slight revision? Generate your key on the local machine, then use `ssh-copy-id` to transmit the public key to the server you want to log into. It's good practise to avoid transmitting private keys over networks, even using utilities like `scp`. You basically want to generate private keys in the location they will be used (here the local machine the user is physically at), and then send the public keys to where they are needed (here the remote server the user wants to log into). ((Argh, did it again, commented on an old post the bot promoted. sorry!))