# SSH: What is the difference between RhostsAuthentication and RSAAuthintication?

Tags: ssh, authentication

What is the difference between RhostsAuthentication and RSAAuthintication?

Can anyone give a small example on both of them?

If we want to use ssh without password? Which method is more prefer and advanced?

Answer (score 0):

Rhosts (rsh) is insecure and easy to spoof (just because of the authentication method), I haven't seen many cases when it makes sense to use it.  It pairs a hostname and username.  So if it was `Kit Ho` on `alphaPC` the `.rhosts` would read something like:

```
alphaPC Kit Ho
```

---

RSA is a public/private key pair to authenticate, so the server **must** have the public key in its `authorized_keys{,2}` file and the client **must** use the private key locally.  Depending on the strength used, cracking would be very difficult.

Rather than me retyping an old answer of how to setup the RSA method, [see my old answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/530016/ssh-rsa-key-with-non-root-user/530063).

Hope that is somewhat helpful.